# Basics of Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, parent-child

Consider a Parent class with some variables say a,b,c. If I derive a child class from this parent class, will the child class know the variables a,b,c?? If so, will the values of a,b,c remain the same in this child class too??

Comment: Please rethink your question or at least post what you have with some code if possible.

Answer (score 2):

OOP-languages have different access levels that determine the visibility of fields ("variables") from outside and inside the class. 
Most OOP-languages have at least the following three: `private`, `protected` and `public`. If your base class variables are `private`, derived classes cannot see them, if they are `protected` they can (but non-derived classes cannot) and if they are `public` everyone can see them - both derived and non-related classes.

Of course, methods in the base class can *always* access private variables in the base class - even if the newly added methods in the derived class cannot see them. Here is an example in C++ (other OOP languages have similar syntax).

```
class Base {
   private: 
     int a;
   protected: 
     int b;
   public: 
     int f() { a = 1; return a + b; }
}

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    int g() {
      // You cannot access a here, so this is illegal:
      a = 2;

      // You can access b here, so this is legal:
      b = 2;

      // Base::f, or parent::f() in Java, can access a, so this will return 1 + 2 = 3.
      return Base::f();
    }
}

class NonRelated {
  void h() {
    Derived d; // Create a derived object

    // Both of these are illegal since neither a nor b is public:
    d.a = 3;
    d.b = 4;

    // You *can* call both f() and g(), because they are both public.
    // This will return 3.
    // (Side note: in actual C++, calling d.f() would not be a good idea since a is not initialized).
    d.g(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are getting at, but the question is not sensible. The child class does not have another copy of the variable: it extends the base class meaning it inherits all its variables and functions but if you instantiate it you don't get an instance of the Base class AND and instance of the Base + Derived class, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

the child class will contain the parent class variables.

If the child class can access them is a different matter. The variables would need to be at least have a protected accessibility for the child class to be able to access and/or use them.

Comment: You cannot access them from the child class, only from within the parent class. You could create a public function in the parent class to set the private field.